# Reading HTML created by JavaScript with Python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a small problem with linking Python with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript: Currently, I have a website that takes in the user's input, and uses JavaScript to modify some of the  tags, so that Python can read it.

However, when I tried the following code:

```
from requests_html import HTMLSession <br>
session = HTMLSession() <br>
r = session.get('https://infiniteembarrasseddesign.lucatu1.repl.co/') <br>
ex = r.html.find("#ex", first=True) <br>
print(ex.text).
```

It doesn't output anything. Well, it does, just an empty element. However, my JavaScript should have replaced the textContent of the div with the user's entry. Is there a way to make Python read HTML created by JavaScript?

My operating system is windows 10.

Here's the HTML code if you want it:

https://repl.it/@LUCATU1/InfiniteEmbarrassedDesign#index.html. The URL of the webpage is in the code.

My apologies that I cannot provide the main code for Python as it involves opening private .mdb files.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that requests.get does not render a JavaScript, in order to test it you can open Dev Tools(F12 - in Chrome) and click "Console" open and type "Disable JavaScript" and refresh the page, after you will see what your web-sraper(**requests**) gets. You can solve this problem by alternative version by using [Selenium](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/).

Answer (score 0):

`requests.get` don't see Javascript, you can try selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.ChromeDriver()

driver.get("URL")
```

And get source using `driver.page_source` or crawl through the page using selenium methods.

Comment: This was very helpful. However, when I tried running it, the screen flashes with a new window, and the program ended with the error SessionNotCreatedException. Also, I needed to replace ChromeDriver() with Chrome("path to chrome driver"). What's wrong here?